# what causes NSPortTimeoutException?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, webkit

I use a cocoa webview to load many web pages one by one for a long time.However,sometimes,the 
console prints as follow:

```
2013-06-04 20:12:32.829 iBookMark[5895:707] ---sender = (null)
2013-06-04 20:12:33.093 iBookMark[5895:707] thumbnail img save over
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
2013-06-04 20:12:48.987 iBookMark[5895:707] [IMKInputSession activate] exception caught.
    IMKInputSession: <IMKInputSession: 0x102124cc0> -- 
    NSPortTimeoutException : connection timeout: did not receive reply
2013-06-04 20:12:53.989 iBookMark[5895:707] [IMKInputSession setValue:forTag:] exception caught.
    NSPortTimeoutException : connection timeout: did not receive reply
```

I search on google.But found nothing.I guess the exception is caused by the cocoa webview,is it right? When this happaned,my system became very slowly,and the memory was nearly zero.How can I solve this,help me,thank you.